# Printing records from database is very slow

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to print records from database, everything works great but it is very slow..
Bootstrap framework is used.

Query

```
 $sql="
SELECT a.ArtId
     , a.ArtSifra
     , a.ArtNaziv
     , a.ArtMinKolic
     , a.ArtKategorija
     , a.ArtAktivan
     , a.ArtRoditelj
     , a.ArtStanjeSa
     , a.ArtStanjeBL
     , b.JmNaziv
     , c.KatNaziv 
  FROM artikli a
  LEFT 
  JOIN mjera b
    ON a.ArtMjera = b.JmId
  LEFT 
  JOIN kategorija c
    ON a.ArtKategorija = c.KatId
 ORDER 
    BY a.ArtKategorija ASC
";

$q = $conn->query($sql);
```

Create table

```
 <thead>
    <tr>
    <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
    <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Id</th>
    <th data-field="sifra" data-sortable="true">Sifra</th>
    <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Naziv</th>
    <th data-field="mjera" data-sortable="true">Jed. mjere</th>
    <th data-field="stanjesa" data-sortable="true">Stanje </th>
    <th data-field="stanjebl" data-sortable="true">Stanje 2</th>
    <th data-field="minkolicina" data-sortable="true">Min</th>
    <th data-field="kategorija" data-sortable="true">Kategorija</th>
    <th data-field="status" data-sortable="true">Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
```

Then I fetch results via while loop

```
<?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
<tbody>
<td data-field="checkbox" data-checkbox="true"> </td>
<td><?=$r['ArtId'] ?> </td>
<td><?=$r['ArtSifra'] ?></td>
<td><?=$r['ArtNaziv'] ?></td>
<td><?=$r['JmNaziv'] ?></td>
<td><?=$r['ArtStanjeSa']?></td>
<td><?=$r['ArtStanjeBL'] ?></td>
<td><?=$r['ArtMinKolic'] ?></td>
<td><?=$r['KatNaziv'] ?></td>
<td><?=$r['ArtAktivan'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</tbody>
```

I was wondering is there a way to get result faster? In this table I have around 1000 rows that needs to be printed. I have tried with stored procedure it is slow also. 
Any help or advice is very appreciated.

Comment: For one you could use pagination, are there indexes on those tables?

Comment: Have you tried profiling to see what part of the code is actually taking all the time? If it's the actual database query, what indexes do you have on your tables?

Comment: So, the query itself isn't slow, just the preparation of the table?

Comment: @user3651819,Have you heard about indexing technique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An index is used to speed up searching in the database.**

Documentation for the indexing : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

An index is used to efficiently **find all records matching some column in your query and then walk through only that subset of the table to find exact matches** of your choice. If you **don't have indexes on any column in the WHERE clause, then the SQL server have to walk through the whole table and check every row to see if it matches, which may be a slow operation** on big tables.

The index can also be a UNIQUE index, which means that you cannot have duplicate values in that column, or a PRIMARY KEY which in some storage engines defines where in the database file the value is stored.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have solved the problem via indexes and table pagination. it works good now

Comment: @user3651819,Glad i could help,can you please accept my answer as a solution for your problem ?

Comment: I have table now which has 18000 records and I have used indexes and pagination printning is very slow

Comment: @user3651819, You need to optimize your queries & check execution time interval.

Comment: Thanks for reply..this is my query SELECT a.Id, a.Ulaz, a.Izlaz, a.Datum, a.Preuzeo, a.VrstaDokumentaBroj, b.ArtNaziv, c.UposlenikImePrezime, d.DokNaziv
FROM kartica_artikla_2014 a
LEFT JOIN artikli b
ON a.Artikal= b.ArtId
LEFT JOIN uposlenici c
ON a.Korisnik = c.UposlenikId
LEFT JOIN kartica_dokumenti d
ON a.VrstaDokumenta=d.DokId
order by a.Id desc   -- Query took 0.0008 seconds

Answer (score 2):

Index the columns that are used for the join. This can be done easily using PHPMyAdmin- just login, find the table, go to structure and click "Index" on the row that is used for the join (Each of the IDs).

Joins should not be run without indexes. As you've seen, it slows them down quite a bit.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use EXPLAIN() to help you better understand your query and if it's using indexes:

[13.8.2 EXPLAIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

Short explanation on what above does can also be found here:

[Explaining MySQL's EXPLAIN](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/explaining-mysqls-explain)

One last thing, how large are those tables?

Comment: one table has 18000 records and now I have trouble again with printing, I have used indexing and pagination